# How can I create SQL table keys with items from looping through a list in Python

Tags: python, sql, list, loops, alter

I have a list called `headers` of about 40-50 items, and I'm trying to make them all keys in a table. I'm trying to avoid typing them all out, here's what I have so far:

```
def createtable_db():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='x', password='x', host='x', database='data')

    mycursor = cnx.cursor()

    create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)"

    for h in headers:
        pop_table = "ALTER TABLE players ADD COLUMN "+ h +" VARCHAR(255)"

    mycursor.execute(create_table)
    mycursor.execute(pop_table)

    cnx.close()

createtable_db()
```

This only adds the very last key, I tried adding a + to make this line:

```
 pop_table += "ALTER TABLE players ADD COLUMN "+ h +" VARCHAR(255)"
```

but that's also not working: it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: give full error of the code. what type of syntax error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following demonstrative code is for generating a `pop_table` string as a sequence of `ALTER TABLE` SQL commands, one for each column to be added. You can

1. create a list for the single columns commands, each of them in the form `ADD columnName column format`
2. populate it with a column data section for each element of `headers`
3. `join` them to build the complete sequence of queries. `ADD` sections have to be separated by commas `,`
4. Append the joined list to initial `ALTER TABLE`. The query is terminated by a semicolon `;`

```py
headers = [ "Stack22", "overflow22", "rules22"]

header_columns_commands =[]

for h in headers:
    header_columns_commands .append("ADD "+ h +" VARCHAR(255)")

pop_table = "ALTER TABLE players " + ",".join(header_columns_commands ) + ";"

print(pop_table)
```

Output:

```
ALTER TABLE players
    ADD Stack VARCHAR(255),
    ADD overflow VARCHAR(255),
    ADD rules VARCHAR(255);
```

Tested on MySQL.

Comment: I get this error: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''player_id' VARCHAR(255),'shortname' VARCHAR(255),'first_name' VARCHAR(255),'las' at line 1

Comment: @TimW Now I checked it and it works. I forgot to insert an "ADD" for every item and I wrongly included `'`s.

Comment: Perfect, worked awesome, had to change varchar to text, but for me thats not going to affect anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `pop_table` to an empty string and then concatenating to it, inside of the for loop.

```
pop_table = ''

for h in headers:
    pop_table += "ALTER TABLE players ADD COLUMN "+ h +" VARCHAR(255)"
```

You could also initialize it to an empty list and append the generated strings

```
pop_table = []

for h in headers:
    pop_table.append("ALTER TABLE players ADD COLUMN "+ h +" VARCHAR(255)")

# join them with you choice of delimiter
joined_up = ','.join(pop_table)
```

Comment: Still getting syntax errors on the pop_table +=/.append line.

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE players ADD COLUMN shortname VARCHAR(255),ALTER TABLE players ADD COLUMN f' at line 1

Comment: It looks like the strings are getting appended, but the SQL commands that they forming together is not valid, try printing out the ALTER TABLE command and check to see if there is anything missing syntax wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
pop_table = "ALTER TABLE players "
for h in headers:
    pop_table += "ADD COLUMN "+ h + " VARCHAR(255), "

#Replace the last , with a ;
pop_table.replace(pop_table[len(pop_table)-1], ';')
mycursor.execute(create_table)
mycursor.execute(pop_table, multi=True)
```

Maybe if you did it like this? Sorry its been a while since I used `mysql.connector`. If I remember correctly, `multi` must be set to `True` if you intend to execute more than one command.

Comment: This added another key, so I have 3 (auto inc id, and 2 from the list - the first and the last in the list)